# Exclude JS files from SonarLint

Tags: eclipse, performance, sonarlint

I use SonarLint in my Eclipse to analyze JAVA web project.

How to exclude `js` files from **SonarLint** analysis?
It is because when I open js file, SonarLint starts to slow down the Eclipse performance.

Used version:

```
SonarLint for Eclipse   1.0.0.20151015-1547-RELEASE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to Window->Preferences, SonarLint->Scanner Properties and add the properties:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/*.js
sonar.test.exclusions=**/*.js
```

More information about this: 
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

SonarLint will still be triggered but it will skip all files that are JS source files. You can tune the exclusions to only exclude a subset of the js files.
Also note that since SonarLint Eclipse 1.1, [derived resources are excluded](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-17) from the analysis.

Comment: Very useful too to ignore jpg, png, gif, log ... wich are analyzed in PHP projects.

Comment: This does not work for me (using the latest Eclipse Sonarlint-Plugin v3.2.x). Reading this discussion (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarlint/sonar.exclusions%7Csort:relevance/sonarlint/aBxnpn-yLbg/m7uBeSo_AgAJ) `sonar.exclusions` shouldn't work right now, since only a limited set is supported so far.

Comment: Unfortunately I have same problem for Intellij :-/

Answer (score 0):

If someone bumps in here looking for steps for **Visual Studio 2015**, here is how its done in Visual Studio:

1. Go to **Tools**>**Options**>**SonarLint For Visual Studio**
2. Click Deactivate

[image: sonarlint]

**And that's it, now js files won't be analyzed**

**Note**: This does not exclude, but **deactivate** Js support. If you want to specify exclusion rules,then mention the same in SonarQube project which is bound in Visual Studio. (In connected mode, [sonarlint uses configuration from SonarQube](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarlint/Hfen0FcDteg/wVJB-aeEBwAJ))