# How to exclude JS files from on-the-fly analysis in SonarLint for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint

I can't figure out, how to exclude specific source files from being analysed by SonarLint on the fly.

The [FAQ](http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/index.html#FAQ) suggest to configure the property `sonar.exclusions`. But SonarLint keeps analysing excluded files when they get opened in IntelliJ.

[Exclude JS files from SonarLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660091/exclude-js-files-from-sonarlint) covers same question for Eclipse, where it seems possible.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1 with SonarLint for IntelliJ IDEA 2.0 on Windows with an analysis property `sonar.exclusions = **\components\**` to exclude some external JavaScript libraries.

Also a property value of `**` or other patterns do not cause SonarLint to exclude any files.

For some large library files I don't want that they get analysed because it degrades performance and the warnings clutter the wohle editor.

Comment: Same, exclusion values of \*, \*\*, \*\*/\* or \*\*/\*.js do not work either.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (with IntelliJ version 2017.2)

[image: sonarLint settings]

Comment: y won't down voters explain the reason when downvoting

Comment: This solution isn't working for me, so I'll downvote it

Comment: @GillesBodart which version of intellij you are using ?

Comment: @ElmaCherb 2017.2.1

Comment: there are some changes in version 2017.3.4 of intellij, and SonarLint 3.2.1.2406. In file exclusion i put only `**/*.js`. In the SonarLint tab at the bottom i have this message when i open a JS file: "This file is not automatically analysed"

Answer (score 1):

Current method to exclude files (feb 2020):

1. Settings
2. Other settings
3. Sonarlint General Settings
4. File exclusions
5. Press '+'

> **/*.js

Answer (score 0):

```
These steps are for 2022 Intellij Ultimate version


Step 1 : Click on Sonarlint tab 
Step 2 : On the left hand side you should search for for settings icons,Click on that icon
Step 3 : You should see a Project settings dialog
Step 4 : Click on + 
Here you can
exclude a file: for example .html
exclude a directory: Example: Browser directory from your machine to 
exclude using Glob pattern : **/*.js  - meaning exclude all js file from sonar analysis
```